# Connect Google Home with iPhone 6 personal hotspot

Tags: iphone, google-home, hotspot

I am trying to use Google Home Mini with iPhone 4g personal hotspot. When I am setting up Google home I get the error You are currently not on the same Wi-Fi network as your device. Please connect to the appropiate network.

Is it possible to connect Google Home with my iPhone personal hotspot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on yourself,
The Google home mini won't connect to the mobile hotspot as the connected device (the phone) isn't connected to the same network.

However, If you have 2 mobile phones, you can use one of them as the main network while the other is running Google Home app and connects to the speaker, then it will work.